# Adding custom rewrite rules to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress site has a portfolio that is at `www.mysite.com/portfolio/`. The portfolio sections and items are administered through a custom plugin I created. I want to access the individual items like `www.mysite.com/portfolio/my-cool-photo` and have that put "my-cool-photo" into a query string like `?portfolio_item=my-cool-photo` so I can read it from my code.

In the plugins activation PHP file I have this code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'portfolio/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?&portfolio_item=$1'
    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');

function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "portfolio_item";

    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

This adds the rewrite rule to the array OK. The problem is it's not doing anything. When I go to `www.mysite.com/portfolio/testing/` I get the "This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?" WordPress 404 error page. Obviously the redirect isn't working, so the query string won't be filled, but just to make sure I did this:

```
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks()) {
    $searchKey = $wp_query->query_vars['portfolio_item'];
} else {
    $searchKey = $_GET['portfolio_item'];
}
```

...and sure enough the query string isn't getting passed.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you update the WordPress rewrite rules, you need to flush them:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

You can choose to flush with the `$hard` parameter `true`, and then you should be able to see your rewrite rules in the .htaccess file.

Comment: In the `add_rewrite_rules` function I added `$wp_rewrite->flush_rewrite_rules(true);` at the end. That didn't affect anything and my htaccess file is still the default WordPress htaccess file.

Comment: you could try using the `add_rewrite_rule` function instead: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: I believe the rewrite is actually working now using `add_rewrite_rule`. The problem it seems is WordPress is not recognizing mysite.com/portfolio/abcdefg/ as being a part of the /portfolio/ page, so it's giving me the "This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?" error screen. Is there something I need to do to "let it know" that it should still be loading the portfolio page?

Comment: I got it! I changed the redirect to `add_rewrite_rule('^portfolio/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/portfolio/?portfolio_item=$matches[1]', 'top');`. The only problem now is that the `portfolio_item` parameter contains "$matches[1]", so for some reason it's not rendering out that variable.

Comment: Another thing, `flush_rewrite_rules()` isn't working. The only way I can flush them is to go to the Permalinks page in the admin and press Save Changes.

Comment: Got it. Changing `$matches[1]` to `$1` fixed it. Not sure why I had to do that. In WordPress' codex it said to use $matches. Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example rewriting url code. Hopefully this will help users.

In this url like http://www.domainname.com/test-page?urltags=ABCD is run as http://www.domainname.com/test-page/ABCD

```
<?php
function add_my_rule() {    
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('tags');
    add_rewrite_rule('test-page/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=test-page&urltags=$matches[1]','top');
}
function add_my_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%urltags%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
add_action('init', 'add_my_tags', 10, 0);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a multiple tag solution?