# Wordpress - Get GET['alias'] value from a custom mysite.com/page/aliashere link

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm new to Wordpress and I can't figure this out.

I have a page in my website that has just a call to a PHP function like so:

[php]getdetails();[/php]

This function is in another file placed in a subfolder in the plugins folder. I'm not sure how that file is included, as someone else did that part, but the call to the function works. So for example if I visit the link below, everything works fine and the details from the database are shown.

mysite.com/page/?alias=aliashere

What I want to do is that the link below should work just the same:

mysite.com/page/aliashere

I've tried searching alot and read up on wp_rewrite and permalink and what not, but nothing seems to make sense or work when I blindly put samples of code in my functions folder. I have not tried modifying the .htaccess file because that just seem too wrong to even try, irrespective of whether it works or not.

Can someone please help me with this or point me in the right direction? I apologize if such a post already exists here. I tried searching but I couldn't find what I needed. Maybe I don't know what exactly to search for.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

---

UPDATE:

I was able to make it work like below. Can someone please check and tell me how I can make this better? It's done the trick, but I have a feeling that it has some unnecessary details to it.

```
function add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
        add_rewrite_rule('page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/page/?alias=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "alias";

    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

SOURCE of help: [Adding custom rewrite rules to WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544460/adding-custom-rewrite-rules-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

```
function add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
        add_rewrite_rule('page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/page/?alias=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```